# How do I invoke methods on my objects in certain IDEs?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, netbeans

I am learning Java with a University that makes use of BlueJ as a learning IDE. It works very differently to full blown IDE's such as Eclipse or Netbeans, but I have these installed (along with IntelliJ) to tryout and move on to.

My question however is if there is a command line where I can simply send message sends to the Classes / packages that I am working on.

In BlueJ you can install extensions, and one such extension is a command line style window where I can fully test any elements of the project simply by invoking methods.

Does such a thing exist in NetBeans / Eclipse / IntelliJ?

Comment: I have you looked into Unit testing?

Comment: In Eclipse you can evaluate expressions while debugging. I'm sure IntelliJ offers something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Tools | JShell Console... runs such an interactive environment in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Yole - Thanks. I will have a look for this and have a test. Someone advised me that the terminology for the feature in BlueJ is a Workspace? But a quick Google of IDE Workspaces does not necessarily confirm this.